# Overriding a method and adding implicit parameter

Tags: scala

I have the following code and I wonder if the nasty thing could be removed. Override doesn't work if I add implicit parameter.

```
class FromEnumFormat[T <: Enum[T]] extends JsonFormat[T] {
  override def read(json: JsValue): T = readit(json)

  def readit(json: JsValue)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {

    val EnumerationClass = m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]

    json match {
      case s: JsString if EnumerationClass.getEnumConstants.map(_.toString.toLowerCase).contains(s) => Enum.valueOf(EnumerationClass, s.value.toUpperCase()).asInstanceOf[T]
      case unknown => deserializationError(s"unknown Status: $unknown")
    }
  }

  override def write(obj: T): JsValue = JsString(obj.name().toLowerCase)
}
```

Is there a way how to get rid of this line

```
override def read(json: JsValue): T = readit(json)
```

The question is essentially: Are the implicit parameters part of method signature?

UPDATE:
Code doesn't compile. So correct solution should be:

```
class FromEnumFormat[T<: Enum[T]] extends JsonFormat[T] {

 implicit val m: Manifest[T] = ???

  override def read(json: JsValue): T = {

    val EnumerationClass  = m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]

    json match {
      case s :JsString if EnumerationClass.getEnumConstants.map(_.toString.toLowerCase).contains(s) => Enum.valueOf(EnumerationClass ,s.value.toUpperCase()).asInstanceOf[T]
      case unknown => deserializationError(s"unknown Status: ${unknown}")
    }
  }

  override def write(obj: T): JsValue = {JsString(obj.name().toLowerCase)}
}
```

The question is how to access Manifest? I am using Scala 2.10

UPDATE:
Find that the issue is with scala reflection not with implicits and overrides, hence closing this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yest, implicit parameters are part of method signature. However, as it is implicit, this means you can call the `def readit(json: JsValue)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T` function without mentioning it, as long as it has been declared somewhere in the code :

```
implicit val manifest = /* whatever a Manifest is*/
readit(jsonValue)
```

Could you please provide an example of what you'd like to do ?

Comment: Yea, tried that. But wasn't able to find the way how to get Manifest :-)

Comment: That's another problem :) You absolutely need a reference it to make it work.

Comment: Actually, does the code that you provided compile ?

Comment: Actually NO,  "No Manifest available for T." As there is no Manifest value available in the scope

Comment: So that means that "call through" doesn't make any sense

Comment: Do you have the package of the Manifest object ?

Answer (score 2):

Your final solution is nearly correct, but it has `m` in the wrong place, it should be a class parameter instead:

```
class FromEnumFormat[T<: Enum[T]](implicit m: Manifest[T]) extends JsonFormat[T] {

  override def read(json: JsValue): T = {

    val EnumerationClass  = m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]

    json match {
      case s :JsString if EnumerationClass.getEnumConstants.map(_.toString.toLowerCase).contains(s) => Enum.valueOf(EnumerationClass ,s.value.toUpperCase()).asInstanceOf[T]
      case unknown => deserializationError(s"unknown Status: ${unknown}")
    }
  }

  override def write(obj: T): JsValue = {JsString(obj.name().toLowerCase)}
}
```

This way the compiler can insert it when creating a `FromEnumFormat` with a specific enum:

```
val format = new FromEnumFormat[TimeUnit]
```

If you want to create a generic `FromEnumFormat[T]`, though, you'll have to pass `implicit m: Manifest[T]` as an argument:

```
def doSomethingWithFormat[T <: Enum[T]](implicit m: Manifest[T]) = {
  val format = new FromEnumFormat[T]
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implicit parameters are <strike>not exactly</strike> part of the signature. <strike>But</strike> So you cannot add an implicit parameter by means of overloading.

Here's why. Multiple parameter list syntax is just a syntactic sugar. The code

```
def readit(json: JsValue)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = ???
```

gets desugared to

```
def readit(json: JsValue): Function1[Manifest[T], T] = {
  def inner(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = ???
  inner
}
```

So as you see the real type of `readit` just doesn't match the type of `read`, thus it is not a proper override.

**UPD.**

As Alexey pointed out formally multiple parameter list contributes to type signature (see section [4.6 Function Declarations and Definitions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#function-declarations-and-definitions) of scala spec).

> A function declaration has the form def fpsig: T, where f is the function's name, psig is its parameter signature and T is its result type.
>
> A parameter signature consists of an optional type parameter clause
> `[tps]`, followed by zero or more value parameter clauses
> `(ps1)…(psn)`.

Comment: "Implicit parameters are not exactly part of the signature." Yes, they are.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, would you mind elaborating a bit? You've seen my arguments, I would like to see yours.

Comment: Well, you can just look at the definition of  signature in section 4.6 of http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html. The "desugaring" is also incorrect (e.g. `readit[Int](value)` in the first case would have type `Int`, in the second it would be `Manifest[Int] => Int`).

Comment: Ok, point taken. Thank you for the reference. As for the "incorrect desugaring" let's refer to the section [3.9 Function Types](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#function-types) of the same spec to find the confirmation that `Manifest[T] => T` is a shorthand for `(Manifest[T]) => T` which is in turn shorthand for `Function1[Manifest[T], T]`.

Comment: Er, yes. My point is that `Manifest[Int] => Int` is different from `Int`. If it was the desugaring, expressions referring to both versions of `readit` should have the same type and result.